# laravel localization using mcamara package giving 404 error on root url but not other urls

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-localization

i am trying to use mcamara package for language translation but on the root url i am getting 404 error. Actually i am trying to detect the ip address of the user and then set the locale according to that country. i stored the locales and country names in the database. Below is my code:

**AppServiceProvider.php** in this file i am fetching user ip address through https://github.com/stevebauman/location this package and checking the locale from database and set the locale according to that.

```
        $ip = request()->getClientIp(); 
        $position = Location::get($ip); 
        $locale = Locale::where('country_code',strtolower($position->countryCode))->first();
        if($locale){
            LaravelLocalization::setLocale($locale->country_code);
            
        }
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::group([
'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale(),
'middleware' => ['localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]], function(){
   Route::get('/',function(){
     dd('check');
  }); 
}
```

i am getting 404 error.

Answer (score 5):

this steps works for me

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]],function (){
// routes here
```

});

then
1 - remove cache files in bootstrap folder
2- `php artisan optimize`
3- `php artisan route:trans:cache`
4- `php artisan cache:clear`
5- `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/blob/master/CACHING.md

this url help to you.
`use \Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\Traits\LoadsTranslatedCachedRoutes;` trait in `RouteServiceProvider`
this problem at `route:trans:cache` instead of `route:cache`

Answer (score -2):

go to bootstrap folder and delete (config.php) file and if there is any file called (route.php) delete it too from bootstrap folder.

Comment: Where did you find this? Please mention your source. I think that it's highly unlikely that this is the solution.

Comment: I face this problem myself, and this solution works for me.